# Comparing user input to dictionary and list

Tags: python, list, dictionary, input

I am trying to finish an assignment for school. I need guidance to make 2 functions. Both functions should input. First function compares input to the value and prints the key. Second one compares input to a list. What i am trying to accomplish is to combine the two, so when the functions are called, they would print the correct index from my *grades* list. Assignment is based on making a program to keep track of subjects and grades in school. This is only a part of the program.

I have made the two functions below.

```py
# These are the lists and dictionaries i use atm

grades = {'INFO100' : 'C','INFO102' : 'B', \
          'INFO125' : 'B','INFO132' : 'A', \
          'INFO180' : '' ,'INFO216' : 'A', \
          'INFO282' : 'C','INFO284' : '' , \
          'ECON100' : 'C','ECON110' : 'C', \
          'ECON218' : '' , 'GEO100' : '' , \
          'GEO113'  : 'D', 'GEO124' : 'D',}


subjects = ['INFO100','INFO102','INFO125',\
           'INFO132','INFO180','INFO216',\
           'INFO282','INFO284','ECON100',\
           'ECON110','ECON218','GEO100' ,\
           'GEO113' ,'GEO124']

subject_code = {'Informatics' : 'INFO',\
                'Economy' : 'ECON',\
                'Geografi' : 'GEO'}

subject_level = [100,200,300,400]

def subject(): 
    for key, value in subject_code.items():
        test = input('- Subject: ')
        if test == key:
            currentValue = print(value)
            break
    level()

def level():
    test2 = int(input('- Subject Level: '))
    for i in emne_nivå:
        if test2 == i:
            pass

def grades(): #Prints all the grades.
    for key, values in grades.items():
        print(key, values)
```

What i am trying to accomplish is to combine the two functions, so when the functions are called, they would print the correct index from my *subjects* list. Printing only subjects from their respective subject_code. If either subject or subject level is an empty string it should print the grades dict.

```py
# This should be the output if you type in both values

- Subject: Economy
- Subject Level: 200
ECON218
ECON221

# This should be the output if the values are empty

- Subject:
- Subject Level:
# This is where i would print the grades dict through a if statement.


# This is my current one

- Subject: Informatics
INFO
- Subject Level: 300
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure why you want to do this in two functions since you can do it in one.
Also, I think you don't the `subject_level` list.

```
grades = {
    'INFO100' : 'C',
    'INFO102' : 'B', 
    'INFO125' : 'B',
    'INFO132' : 'A',
    'INFO180' : '',
    'INFO216' : 'A',
    'INFO282' : 'C',
    'INFO284' : '',
    'ECON100' : 'C',
    'ECON110' : 'C',
    'ECON218' : '',
    'GEO100' : '', 
    'GEO113'  : 'D',
    'GEO124' : 'D'
}


subjects = [
    'INFO100','INFO102','INFO125', 'INFO132','INFO180','INFO216','INFO282',
    'INFO284','ECON100','ECON110','ECON218','GEO100' ,'GEO113' ,'GEO124'
]

subject_code = {
    'Informatics' : 'INFO',
    'Economy' : 'ECON',
    'Geografi' : 'GEO'
}

def get_grade():
    subject = input('- Subject: ')
    level = input('- Subject Level: ')
    code = subject_code[subject]
    level_number = level[:1]
    subject_code_level = f'{code}{level_number}'
    if level_number == '' or code =='':
        print(grades)
    else:
        for key, value in grades.items():
            if key[:5] == subject_code_level:
                if value == '':
                    print('No grade yet')
                else:
                    print(f'Course: {key}, Grade: {value}')
```

Comment: It feels somewhat hardcoded. If i was to type Informatics it would still spit out ECON subjects and their grade. I just need the input of Informatics or Economy/Geografi/Informatics to resemble the output which are in subjects, also at 100, 200, 300 level. All the INFO subject codes are ofc Informatics, all the ECON subject codes are Economy and all the GEO subject codes are Geografi. Grade is not relevant yet, as i would print all of the grade separately IF there was nothing being input.

Comment: Yes, I saw a mistake there with _Economy_ in the Dict.